# Calculated field is not updated when fields that it is calculated from are updated using PATCH in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    available_from = models.DateTimeField()
    available_to = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

`MyModelManager` adds a calculated field `is_active` based on `available_from` and `available_to` like so:

```
class SprintTypeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .annotate(
                is_active=expressions.Case(
                    expressions.When(
                        Q(available_from__lte=Now()) & Q(available_to__gte=Now()),
                        then=expressions.Value(True),
                    ),
                    default=expressions.Value(False),
                    output_field=fields.BooleanField(),
                )
            )
        )
```

This works well, I get the three fields on the API, I can order by them and I can filter by them.

However, if I update `available_from` or `available_to` such that `is_active` should change using PATCH, that change isn't reflected in the returned body, only if I reload the object using `GET`.

As a workaround, I could re-fetch the object in the serialiser class' `to_representation()` method, but I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: There's nothing DRF specific here... can I assume that `SprintTypeManager.get_queryset` is being called from a ViewSet's `get_queryset` method somewhere or something?

Comment: @RishiG Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

This value is calculated when the query is fetched from the database. I think it'd be better to make this a property on the model itself, like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    available_from = models.DateTimeField()
    available_to = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return (self.available_from <= datetime.now() and self.available_to >= datetime.now() 

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

You should include this property as a field on the serializer class as well:

```
is_active = serializers.Field()
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this (though I'd put the field on the serializer), but that's code duplication, the same logic is in the queryset annotation and the field.